# Phalcon PHP: Uniqueness across columns

Tags: php, validation, unique, phalcon

The Phalcon docs mention being able to du a multiple column uniqueness validation, but they don't provide an example of how.  Do I just send an array as the "field" value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can validate uniqueness across multiple columns using an array containing the field names as the value of the 'field' key for the validator.

```
public function validation(){
    $this->validate(new Uniqueness(array(
    'field' => array('email', 'name')
    )));
}
```

http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/4205/phalcon-model-validate-uniqueness-by-two-fields